# Discovery's Weird JSON, SQL Server, and OPENJSON

Tags: json, sql-server

I am using an API from Discovery to extract some information from our virtual machines but the JSON for some reasons have the headings in one node and the values in another and they are in square brackets and I am having a hard getting to the end result.

This is a watered-down version of the JSON

```
DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(max) = N'[
    {
        "headings": [
            "vm_type",
            "Hostname"
            ],
        "results": [
            [
                "AWS EC2 Instance",
                null
            ],
            [
                "AWS EC2 Instance",
                null
            ]
        ]
    }
]'

SET @JSON = SUBSTRING(@JSON,2,LEN(@JSON) - 2)
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON)

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON,'$.results')
```

Is there a way to turn this into a table with the headings as column names and the results in the same order as its value?

Comment: Look up how to query JSON arrays, don't use string functions to parse them

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will look at it after I'm done with my current task

Comment: Just checking, does anybody know what "Discovery" is in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of arrays, so **this is effectively a dynamic pivot.**

To do a dynamic pivot you need dynamic SQL. The easiest way to pivot is not usually to use `PIVOT` but to use conditional aggregation with `MAX(CASE`

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
SELECT
  ' + (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(
        QUOTENAME(j.value) + N' = MAX(CASE WHEN j2.[key] = ' + j.[key] + ' THEN j2.value END)',
        ',
  ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY j.[key])
    FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, '$[0].headings') j
) + '
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, ''$[0].results'') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.value) j2
GROUP BY
  j1.[key];
';

PRINT @sql; --for testing

EXEC sp_executesql
  @sql,
  N'@JSON nvarchar(max)',
  @JSON = @JSON;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dfeb303ece0e6332db28163cdfe7b1bf)

Note correct use of `QUOTENAME` to quote column names, and use of `sp_executesql` with a parameter to pass in actual data, rather than injecting it directly into the query text.

Comment: Thanks, I had to add GROUP BY j1.key to get all the rows since your query only returned one row but this was the perfect answer =D

Comment: Good point, have modified